# PHP / MySQL user authorizations

Tags: php, mysql

I create a site for my company based on PHP and MySQL.

I tried to find informations about how handle pages authorizations but I didn't find.

I have multiple sections on my site ( A, B and C for example). Each user belong to a group.

I must indicate which group can create/update/read/delete informations.

For example basic user can edit ( so read ) A.1 / view A.2 / delete ( so read - edit) B.1 etc...

How do you handle this kind of things ?

Group must be hierarchical too, for example admin got every role of user + ...

Thank for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: Keep in mind "access control" and "authorization control" are often two different things. Access = username/password or "Login with Facebook" type restrictions. Authorization = "You can't edit this post because you're not the creator"

Comment: Yes access control is ok, it's for authorizations now to avoid bad stuff

Answer (score -2):

You will need to create the roles in your database, and assign roles to each user - possibly through a relational table. After that, you run a query at the top of each page (or before every specific command like edit/delete) and determine whether user X has role Y.

For more details, edit your question adding some of your code so I can give you an example.

Answer (score -2):

In the past I've done it via rank numbers that are attached to a user's entry in the database.

Ranks:

1 = Standard user

2 = Editor

3 = Admin

You can then run a check at the top of the page to determine if the current user's rank matches into those numbers. So when you're pulling the user information at they log in, store their rank into a session variable and then use that throughout.

If a page can be viewed by all people, make a check for:

```
if (currentUserRank >= 1)
```

Viewed by only editors and up:

```
if (currentUserRank >= 2)
```

Only admins:

```
if (currentUserRank == 3)
```

Obviously you can define how many ranks you want and what each rank is able to do.

If a user does not meet those requirement, redirect them back to a page they are allowed to visit. Note, even if you hide navigation buttons, if the person knows the link they can still access the page. That's why it's best to place that code at the top of the page before it loads.

Comment: It means that if I have 10 roles and 20 types of actions I must create xx differents authorizations ?

Comment: Not entirely. Provided you set up your ranks correctly, you will only require 1 IF and 1 ELSE as it should be inclusive.